# Smoke sim is not visible in render view unless I go inside the domain

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Smoke sim is not visible in render view unless I go inside the domain? I added material for the domain too. I have done everything  and checked YTube[![material[image: ][1][1]]

Comment: What do you mean by "go inside the domain"? And where is your smoke domain located? In your screenshot I see lots of objects/collections with disabled viewport visibility. And what do you mean you have done "everything"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check that your scale is correct for the simulation you want. Simulations can be effected by domain size.

Adjust your camera end clip.
Select the camera then in the camera property tab. Under Lens there is a Clip Start, Clip end.  Increase the Clip end larger.
Also if you are using Evee, select render property then under volumetric there is a start and end field.  Increase end.

For the viewpoint in the top right corner select view, there is a clip start end field for the view,  increase End.